# google compute engine upgrade mysql 5.1.73 to 5.6.x

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

Have a Google cloud Compute Engine VM instance, on which installed MySql using yum install. Didn't realize it was 5.1.73.
Tried "sudo yum update mysql-server" but it says "No Packages marked for Update".
The references used by yum install are as follows:
 * base: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * extras: mirrors.kernel.org
 * updates: mirror.web-ster.com

Cloud someone help upgrading the MySql to 5.6.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall MySQL 5.1.73 from your VM using "yum remove package-name" command.

Download rpm package of MySQL 5.6.20 el6 for Red Hat 6 /CentOS (MySQL-server-5.6.20-1.el6.x86_64.rpm) from official website: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Install it using  rpm -ivh "rpm package file" command.